# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'ConfigProto'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I import tensorflow (version 1.13.1) and need `ConfigProto`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

config = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=8,
    inter_op_parallelism_threads=8,
    allow_soft_placement=True,device_count = {'CPU' : 1, 'GPU' : 1})
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'ConfigProto'
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure you have TF 1.13 and not 2.0? `ConfigProto` seems to have been removed in 2.0.

Comment: Yes, I am sure about that.

Answer (score 124):

ConfigProto disappeared in tf 2.0, so an elegant solution is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

and then replace:

`tf.ConfigProto` by `tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto`

In fact, the compatibility built in 2.0 to get tf 1.XX: `tf.compat.v1` is really helpful.

Useful link: 
Migrate your tensorflow 1. code to tensorflow 2.:
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate

Answer (score 34):

I had similar issues, when upgraded to Python 3.7 & Tensorflow 2.0.0 (from Tensorflow 1.2.0)

**This is an easy one and works!**

If you don't want to touch your code, just add these 2 lines in the main.py file w/ Tensorflow code:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

And that's it!!
**NOW** Everything should run seamlessly :)

Comment: Got a lot of votes! so... if you're voting down please have the courtesy to leave a comment and let me know why

Answer (score 14):

**Just an addition to others looking for an answer for Tensorflow v2**

As the others have mentioned, you can use the back-compatability to v1. But Tensorflow v2 does actually come with its own implementation of this. It is just a hidden experimental feature.

This is how to allow the GPU to grow in memory in Tensorflow v2:

```
# Allow memory growth for the GPU
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
```

More info found [@Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/experimental)

Comment: Does this code disables the GPU use. Earlier my code use to run with 1.8GB GPU memory occupied. Now its just 191 MB and all processing is done at CPU. I can see it in task manager.

Answer (score 7):

If using tensorflow version > 2.0:

```py
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was with a similar error, but i had tensorflow 1.14, ubuntu 18.04 and GTX 1050ti. So a installed properly conda (lastest version - 5.1) 
even with this the error persisted, so a upgraded tensorflow/tensorflow-gpu to -version tensorflow==2.0.0-beta0 and worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Info:

```
RTX 2080
ubuntu 16.04
cuda 10.0
cuDNN v7.4.1.5
Python V 3.5
```

pip list:

```
tensorflow (1.13.1)
tensorflow-gpu (1.13.1)
tf-nightly-gpu (1.14.1.dev20190509)
```

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```

output:

> Created TensorFlow device
>   (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 7439 MB memory) ->
>   physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2080, pci bus id:
>   0000:02:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)

That works for me !