# How can I fix AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'ConfigProto'

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, style-transfer

I am new to deep learning and I get the following error when I try to run the command *for image style transfer* given in a tutorial I am using to learn.

```
python evaluate.py --checkpoint ./rain-princess.ckpt --in-path <path_to_input_file> --out-path ./output_image.jpg
```

I have scipy 1.1.0 installed. *(downgraded to fix the issues AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'imread')*.

I have Tensorflow installed. I have pillow installed.

Please note that I do not have the knowledge to edit any file, I am just copying the commands to see how it executes.

[A screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWifz.jpg)

Comment: sometime you just need to google the error [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33504) or for your question it's a duplicate of this [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56994817/11225821)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'ConfigProto'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56127592/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-configproto)

Comment: Hi @henrywongkk thank you for your suggestion, however, I have read the post and several others and tried the some of the solutions proffered which I can try but it did not solve the problem hence I had to post is as a new question after several days of research.

Comment: Hi @LinhNguyen thank you for your contribution I appreciate. However, I have tried it several times but no luck.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be because you are using tensorflow 2.0 (when installing tensorflow by default it installs 2.0 now). Seems like your evaluvate.py file is suited to execute with tensorflow 1.* as it searches for configproto that is absent in 2.0 So downgrade tensorflow by

```
pip install tensorflow==1.14
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro, you have saved me from brain straining problem for days now. 

You are the best!