# what does set_memory_growth do in tensorflow2

Tags: keras, gpu, tensorflow2.0, ubuntu-server

I'm training a cnn on ubuntu server with keras and tensorflow 2.  If I run my code without the added code below for memory growth, it throws the error I've posted below.  I checked my driver memory and I've posted it below.  It looks like my graphics card was running out of memory.  I've posted my original code, and error below.  I got the added memory growth code from the SO post below.  The post says it allows the gpu memory to grow, I'm wondering what that means?  Also when I check after running the additional code it still shows that I have a gpu device enabled, so does that mean that my code is still being run on gpu after I run the additional code below to allow gpu memory to grow?

post referenced:

[AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'ConfigProto'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56127592/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-configproto)

added code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
```

code:

```
nvidia-smi
```

output:

```
Tue Mar  8 14:52:55 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.103.01   Driver Version: 470.103.01   CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:42:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   37C    P8    10W / 260W |   7970MiB /  7979MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2607      C   ...a3/envs/tf-gpu/bin/python     7967MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

original code:

code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Flatten

model = Sequential()

# CONVOLUTIONAL LAYER
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(4,4),input_shape=(28, 28, 1), activation='relu',))
# POOLING LAYER
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# FLATTEN IMAGES FROM 28 by 28 to 764 BEFORE FINAL LAYER
model.add(Flatten())

# 128 NEURONS IN DENSE HIDDEN LAYER (YOU CAN CHANGE THIS NUMBER OF NEURONS)
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))

# LAST LAYER IS THE CLASSIFIER, THUS 10 POSSIBLE CLASSES
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))


model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


model.summary()
```

output:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 25, 25, 32)        544       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 12, 12, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 4608)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 128)               589952    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 10)                1290      
=================================================================
Total params: 591,786
Trainable params: 591,786
Non-trainable params: 0
```

code:

```
model.fit(x_train,y_cat_train,epochs=10)
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-bed1e94810c6> in <module>
----> 1 model.fit(x_train,y_cat_train,epochs=10)

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
     64   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
     65     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
---> 66       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
     67 
     68     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
    846                 batch_size=batch_size):
    847               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
--> 848               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
    849               # Catch OutOfRangeError for Datasets of unknown size.
    850               # This blocks until the batch has finished executing.

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    578         xla_context.Exit()
    579     else:
--> 580       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    581 
    582     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    642         # Lifting succeeded, so variables are initialized and we can run the
    643         # stateless function.
--> 644         return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
    645     else:
    646       canon_args, canon_kwds = \

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2418     with self._lock:
   2419       graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 2420     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2421 
   2422   @property

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs)
   1659       `args` and `kwargs`.
   1660     """
-> 1661     return self._call_flat(
   1662         (t for t in nest.flatten((args, kwargs), expand_composites=True)
   1663          if isinstance(t, (ops.Tensor,

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1743         and executing_eagerly):
   1744       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
-> 1745       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
   1746           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1747     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    591       with _InterpolateFunctionError(self):
    592         if cancellation_manager is None:
--> 593           outputs = execute.execute(
    594               str(self.signature.name),
    595               num_outputs=self._num_outputs,

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     57   try:
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

UnknownError:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[node sequential/conv2d/Conv2D (defined at <ipython-input-19-bed1e94810c6>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_753]

Function call stack:
train_function
```